# Perf power consumption for a multi-socket system

Tags: performance, intel, perf, energy, msr

I am trying to use Perf event `power/energy-pkg` to measure the energy consumed by the CPU package. I wonder if the number reported by Perf includes all sockets in the system or does it only account for one socket? Here is an example how I use Perf for my use case:

`perf stat -e power/energy-pkg/ $program`

Comment: `pkg` stands for "package", the thing that physically goes in a socket.  I'm not sure if it aggregates it across sockets, though; I haven't used `perf` on a multi-socket system.

Comment: `perf stat` has a switch `--per-socket` which may display the energy consumed per socket.

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita Thank you so much. That implies that by default, `perf stat` reports the whole system energy if `--per-socket` is not specified.